# How do I upload an image from iOS app (built with Kony) to AWS S3 using aws-sdk for javascript?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, temenos-quantum

I am using Kony Visualizer (a low code platorm) to build a mobile app (builds an iOS and Android native app) that can post images taken by the user to an s3 bucket. I am currently using the aws sdk for js (easy import into this low code platform) and am trying to use an s3.putObject call to push the image up. I have found that I can push the base64 string of the image's rawbytes to s3 storage from an Android device, but am unsuccessful in doing so from an iOS device. I have posted this on the Kony forum too at [this link](https://basecamp.kony.com/s/question/0D56A00000rsvosSAA/how-do-i-upload-an-image-from-ios-app-to-aws-s3) and will paste my code below. Also, I know the connection to s3 is working, because I am posting csv files to the same bucket in another part of my code.

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: <accessKeyId>,
    secretAccessKey: <secretAccessKey>,
    region: <region>
});

var rawImg = this.view.Picture.rawBytes;
var b64img = kony.convertToBase64(rawImg);

var bucketImage = new AWS.S3();
var paramsImage = {
    Bucket: <bucket-name>,
    Key: "images/imageB64.jpg",
    ContentType: 'image/jpg',
    Body: b64img};

bucketImage.putObject(paramsImage, function(err,res){
    if (err) {
        alert(err);}
    else {
        alert('Success');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to paste the stack trace here ?

Comment: I'm sure the FFI option would have worked, but I found that once I added the App Transport Security Settings -- Allow Arbitrary Loads - YES to my Info.plist, these uploads started working. Apparently this uses http headers, which iOS doesn't automatically allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the FFI option would have worked, but I found that once I added the App Transport Security Settings -- Allow Arbitrary Loads - YES to my Info.plist in Xcode, and , these uploads started working. Apparently this uses http headers, which iOS doesn't automatically allow. I also had to add the following JSON to my infoplist_configuration.json file under my project in Kony Workspace:
"NSAppTransportSecurity" :
    {
        "NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" : true
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you continue having trouble doing the photo upload using the AWS SDK for JS, try the alternative route of creating a [Foreign Function Interface (FFI)](http://docs.kony.com/6_5/konylibrary/studio/studio_user_guide/Content/Foreign_Function_Interface_JS.htm) and using the AWS SDK for iOS.  That's how the developer on my team got S3 uploads working in our Kony app.

He used the `AWSS3TransferManager` and `AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest` classes to do this.

[Here's a code example in Swift](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/image-upload-to-amazon-aws-s3-bucket-code-example-in-swift/)

Comment: I tried this, but when I import the AWS SDK for iOS, I get the following Visualizer error: "The library should contain [at least one '.h' and at least one of '.a' or '.m' files] (or) [at least one .swift file]"  When I look in the zipped file, all I see is .h files within the different frameworks. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have never tried to import the AWS SDK into Visualizer.  In my build process, I use Visualizer to just generate the JS and the Xcode project files, then I switch over to XCode and that's where I integrate the AWS SDK into the project.  I'm NOT saying that the way I do it is the best way, in fact I think it's a PITA, but that's how I've gotten it working.

Comment: Ahhh I had debated trying that, but figured there had to be some way to get it working within the studio. I'll update back after I've tried that, thanks for your replies!